# Bigcommerce get options from Filters API

Tags: api, filter, bigcommerce

I'm currently making a e-commerce site trough the bigcommerce Filters V3 API.
For this, I'm trying to make a filter. I can sccesfully get the available filters as described in the [docs](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/settings/search-filters/getavailable), but it's unclear to me where to go next.

As the docs state, I get an array of objects containing `id`, `type` and and `name` and optionally `price_range` and `product_count`. However, I don't understand how to get the options for each filter?

An example of the response I get from the Filters API:

```
{
  "data": [
    { "id": "YnJhbmQ=", "type": "brand", "name": "Brand", "product_count": 2 },
    {
      "id": "cmF0aW5n",
      "type": "rating",
      "name": "Rating",
      "product_count": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "cHJpY2U=",
      "type": "price",
      "name": "Price",
      "price_range_min": 9.95,
      "price_range_max": 225
    },
    {
      "id": "Q29sb3I=",
      "type": "product",
      "name": "Color",
      "product_count": 1
    },
    { "id": "U2l6ZQ==", "type": "product", "name": "Size", "product_count": 1 },
    { "id": "Ym9vbA==", "type": "other", "name": "Other" }
  ],
  "meta": {}
}
```

I would expect each filter to contain the available options, but this does not seem the case.
Can someone help me figure out how to get the options for each filter?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit for clarification: so my goal is to get the option values of a filter. E.g. the values `red`, `green`, `blue`" for the `colors` filter.

Answer (score 0):

so there are a couple endpoints to look at in the docs when working with filters.

If you're trying to get this type of data:

```
{ 
    "data": [
        {
          "collapsed_by_default": false,
          "display_name": "Category",
          "display_product_count": true,
          "id": "Y2F0ZWdvcnk=",
          "is_enabled": true,
          "items_to_show": 15,
          "type": "category"
        },
        {
          "collapsed_by_default": false,
          "display_name": "Brand",
          "display_product_count": true,
          "id": "YnJhbmQ=",
          "is_enabled": true,
          "items_to_show": 10,
          "sort_by": "alpha",
          "type": "brand"
        },
        {
          "collapsed_by_default": false,
          "display_name": "Size",
          "display_product_count": true,
          "id": "U2l6ZQ==",
          "is_enabled": true,
          "items_to_show": 10,
          "sort_by": "alpha",
          "type": "product"
        },
        ...
       }
      ]
     }
```

(try using this instead)
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/settings/search-filters/getenabled
Returns the enabled filters with the attached configuration for each.

(what you're using)
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/settings/search-filters/getavailable
Returns what filters are available. Meaning before any configurations, which is done when you set up your catalog.

Comment: Thanks for your help once again Heather!
This isn't entirely what I am looking for.
I want to get the option values of a filter. So for example for the filter `color`, how would I be able to get the options `red`, `green`, `blue`?

(I updated my original question. Sorry for the confusion)

Comment: Hi @Yorg, I understand now. Thank you for that! So, BigCommerce doesn't have a public API for this at the moment. However, we're working on adding it to GraphQL Storefront API. Once this happens, you'll be able to use in the storefront context. :)

Comment: @HeatherBarr I'm running into a similar issue.  Any update on the development of the GraphQL Storefront API for filter values?  If its not available for the "public API", is it available for any other versions of APIs that BigCommerce hosts?

Comment: Hey @CaleSweeney! Is this what you're looking for -- https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/da7d314be4d9e-storefront-graph-ql-s-faceted-and-textual-search? Just released :)

Comment: @HeatherBarr Yes it is!  A big thanks to you and the BigCommerce team for that new GraphQL update!